# Resize div on click using JQuery to specific size

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have a current resizing div code which works however it only resizes the div slightly and i am not sure how to edit the code so that the div resizes to a specific size!

Any help much appreciated!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){    
$(".expanderHead").click(function(){
    var $exsign = $("#expanderSign");
    $(this).find("#expanderContent").slideToggle();
    $exsign.html($exsign.text() == '+' ? '-': '+');   
    // simplify your if/else into one line using ternary operator
    // if  $exsign.text() == "+" then use "-" else "+"
    });    
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Where/how are you providing it a target size?

Comment: this is where i am confused, because it is resizing slightly, but i cannot see where it defines the target size, any ideas?

Comment: `.slideToggle` will cause the element to collapse, or expand. Its behavior changes based on the state of the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of this:

```
$(this).find("#expanderContent").slideToggle();
```

do this:

```
$(this).find("#expanderContent").animate({height: '50px'});
```

**Update**

See the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/csQYN/

As pointed by @JonathanSampson, `slideToggle()` will also save the previous state (the one to toggle back to). You you `animate`, you should be responsible to implement that.

Comment: thankyou for your reply, so how would i get the div to expand to the full size of the text in the div, would i set the height to 100%?